# ASSIMP & paintGL() ,slow rendering (and crash)

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I am using Assimp to load a .3ds file, and a QGLWidget derived class to draw it using PaintGL(). It works with small .3ds files (some KBytes) but if i try to render bigger files (like 1MBytes) the application crashes. Is my way too bad and twisted? Am I doing something wrong?

With qDebug i understand that paintGL() works correctly.The problem is in ourRender method,because if i obscure the

```
for (int t = 0; t < p->getFaces().count(); ++t)
```

and in detail

```
glVertex3f(f.getVerticesArray()[s].getX(),f.getVerticesArray();
```

cycle it all works fast (but obviously nothing is painted) except grid and axis.With it,and loading some complicated 3ds,it crashes

my hardware is

```
Phenom II X3 2.10ghz,4GB and 6650M (last drivers)
```

On a Celeron 2.1 Ghz it crash
BUT on a i7 the program starts but render @2FPS (if I dont use "ourRender" method,it renders at 120fps on my pc)

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
qDebug << "Start PaintGL() #" << times;
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

gluLookAt(objCamera->mPos.x,  objCamera->mPos.y,  objCamera->mPos.z,
              0, objCamera->mView.y, 0,
              objCamera->mUp.x,   objCamera->mUp.y,   objCamera->mUp.z);        

if (drawLines) glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
else glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);

draw_grid();
drawAxis();

ourRender(this->scenaa);
qDebug << "Close PaintGL() #" << times;
}
```

And this is the "ourRender" method:

```
void GLWidget::ourRender(const Scene* sc){

QHash<QString, SceneObject*>& hash=sc->getObj();
double molt =1/20;
int counter =0;
for (QHash<QString,SceneObject*>::ConstIterator i = hash.begin();i!=hash.end();++i) {
    aiMatrix4x4 minchia(1,0,0,molt*20,0,1,0,molt*20,0,0,1,molt*20,0,0,0,1);
    aiTransposeMatrix4(&minchia);
    glPushMatrix();
    const Mesh* p = dynamic_cast<Mesh*>(i.value());
    glMultMatrixf((float*) &minchia);
    if(p){
        for (int t = 0; t < p->getFaces().count(); ++t) {
            Face f = p->getFaces()[t];
            GLenum face_mode;
            switch(f.getVerticesArray().count()) {
            case 1: face_mode = GL_POINTS; break;
            case 2: face_mode = GL_LINES; break;
            case 3: face_mode = GL_TRIANGLES; break;
            default: face_mode = GL_POLYGON; break;
            }
            glBegin(face_mode);
            QList<Vector3D> lista = f.getVerticesArray();
            for(int s = 0; s < lista.count(); s++) {
                if (p->getNormals().count()>0)
      --------->glVertex3f(f.getVerticesArray()[s].getX(),f.getVerticesArray()[s].getY(),f.getVerticesArray()[s].getZ());
            }
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    glPopMatrix();
    molt+=13;
    counter++;
}
glPopMatrix();
}
```

...in the derived QGLWidget class costructor...

```
SceneImporter* aa = new AssimpAdapter();
Scene * nuovo=aa->importFile("C:/Users/nicola/Desktop/Source/aces.3ds");
scenaa=nuovo;
```

Comment: Get rid of OpenGL 1 if possible.

Comment: Where does it crash? When you load the .3ds file? When you do the rendering? Do some debugging to find this out then edit your question.

Comment: edited,i just tried it on another PC (i7) and it works.If u have time to help me,you can find the details above.

Comment: method updated,but we had still the same problems.See above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimizazion.The fact is that for every vertex we were accessing to a QList 3 times.Now we've modified it,and instead of Qlist we use a Vector3D* array that saves the position of the vertices and so we can use the GL method glVertex3fv((GLfloat*)array[numface].posvertex); So,given the pointer to the face,its much faster than before (4 to 10 fps on the same scene).

```
void GLWidget::ourRender(Scene *sc){
QHash<QString, SceneObject*>& hash=sc->getObj();
aiMatrix4x4 m;
for (QHash<QString,SceneObject*>::ConstIterator i = hash.begin();i!=hash.end();++i) {

    aiTransposeMatrix4(&m);
    glPushMatrix();
    Mesh* p = dynamic_cast<Mesh*>(i.value());
    glMultMatrixf((float*) &m);
    if(p){
        QList<Face>& faccie=p->getFaces();
        int numerofacce=faccie.count();
        for (int t = 0; t < numerofacce; ++t) {
            Face& f = faccie[t];
            GLenum face_mode;
            Vector3D* lista=f.arrayVertici;

            switch(f.getVerticesArray().count()) {
            case 1:
                face_mode = GL_POINTS;
                glBegin(face_mode);
                glVertex3fv((GLfloat*)lista[0].pos);
                break;
            case 2:
                face_mode = GL_LINES;
                glBegin(face_mode);
                glVertex3fv((GLfloat*)lista[0].pos);
                glVertex3fv((GLfloat*)lista[1].pos);
                break;
            case 3:
                face_mode = GL_TRIANGLES;
                glBegin(face_mode);
                glVertex3fv(&lista[0].pos[0]);
                glVertex3fv(&lista[1].pos[0]);
                glVertex3fv(&lista[2].pos[0]);
                break;
            default: face_mode = GL_POLYGON; break;
            }
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    glPopMatrix();
    counter++;
}
glPopMatrix();
```

}

Where Vector3D is initialized like this:

```
Vector3D::Vector3D(double x, double y, double z) {
setX(x);
setY(y);
setZ(z);
pos[0]=x;   //vertex1
pos[1]=y;   //vertex2
pos[2]=z;   //vertex3
}
```

PS:Grimmy suggests me to use DisplayLists (discovered right now).Tomorrow I will try them.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem modifying "ourender" method (using references instead of copyes)

```
void GLWidget::ourRender(Scene *&sc){

QHash<QString, SceneObject*>& hash=sc->getObj();
int counter =0;
for (QHash<QString,SceneObject*>::ConstIterator i = hash.begin();i!=hash.end();++i) {
    aiMatrix4x4 m;
    aiTransposeMatrix4(&m);
    glPushMatrix();
    const Mesh* p = dynamic_cast<Mesh*>(i.value());
    glMultMatrixf((float*) &m);
    if(p){
        //apply_material(aaFuori.GetScene()->mMaterials[counter]);
        QList<Face>& faccie=p->getFaces();
        for (int t = 0; t < faccie.count(); ++t) {
            Face f = faccie[t];
            GLenum face_mode;
            switch(f.getVerticesArray().count()) {
            case 1: face_mode = GL_POINTS; break;
            case 2: face_mode = GL_LINES; break;
            case 3: face_mode = GL_TRIANGLES; break;
            default: face_mode = GL_POLYGON; break;
            }
            glBegin(face_mode);
            QList<Vector3D>& lista = f.getVerticesArray();
            int conta=lista.count();
            glVertex3f(lista[0].x,lista[0].y,lista[0].z);
            glVertex3f(lista[1].x,lista[1].y,lista[1].z);
            glVertex3f(lista[2].x,lista[2].y,lista[2].z);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    glPopMatrix();
    counter++;
}
```

Now we can render 8MBytes .3Ds @4fps during camera rotations (instead of application crash).Could someone of you give us an opinion about this result?is it good or bad?

Comment: This is still extremely slow for such a small scene, but might be acceptable for immediate mode. It might be extremely trivial to generate display lists here instead. That can give you a MASSIVE performance boost.

Comment: we've modified it again.The fact is that for every vertex we were accessing to a QList 3 times.Now we've modified it,and instead of Qlist we use a Vector3D* array that saves the position of the vertices and so we can use the GL method glVertex3fv((GLfloat*)array[numface].posvertex);

So,given the pointer to the face,its much faster than before (2.5X,4 to 10 fps).


About displaylist...Is this (http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_displaylist.html) a good start point to look at?Will them boost up a lot more?could you give us a %(circa)?

I'll update here my new method

Comment: I've read that DisplayList is deprecated "If and only if there is a requirement to maintain existing legacy code and there is no way to rewrite the rendering system, using display lists can be quite advantageous in comparison to vertex arrays for static data. If dynamic updates are required, there is no way arround vertex arrays."

from there:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113989/why-were-display-lists-deprecated-in-opengl-3-1

Comment: It's deprecated in newer versions of OpenGL, but so are immediate mode and the matrix stacks (everything you are currently doing). Yes, that guide is enough. Display lists can be extremely quick to add. It should at least remove any latency caused by constructing the mesh data (such as the optimization you mentioned). There's definitely something to gain from it for bigger scenes. The second option is to use VBOs/VAOs and shaders, but that requires a complete system and draw code rewrite.

Comment: Thank you Grimmy,tomorrow I'll try them and I'll let you know here.Hope you check this thread again!